# convert jchararray to jstring in JNI

Tags: c, java-native-interface

I am using JNI below code to convert jchararray to jstring but i am getting only first character in Linux.

```
 char *carr =(char*)malloc(length+1);
(*env)->GetCharArrayRegion(env, ch, 0, length, carr);
return  (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, carr);
```

Comment: Amp up your compiler warnings (and use perhaps other source code inspection tools). Try -Wall -Wextra or equivalent and then back off from there by excluding specific ones that are really uninteresting to you and you don't want to change your code to pass. (Of course, consider reenabling them when testing why your code makes unexplained things happen.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetCharArrayRegion` returns Java chars, i.e. **UTF-16** code points. And `jchar`s in JNI, and they're not null-terminated, and you cannot use [`NewStringUTF`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#NewStringUTF), which expects a null-terminated string comprising bytes in the *modified* UTF-8 encoding.

First, allocate the correct amount of memory

```
jchar *carr = malloc(length * sizeof(jchar));
```

Then execute the `GetCharArrayRegion`

```
(*env)->GetCharArrayRegion(env, ch, 0, length, carr);
```

Then notice that you've got an array of UTF-16 characters. If the first character falls into the ASCII range, and the architecture is little-endian, it is expected that you'd just "get the first character", because the MSB **byte** of the first `jchar` will be zero, and [`NewStringUTF`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#NewStringUTF) would consider this the terminator. Use [`NewString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#NewString) instead:

```
return (*env)NewString(env, carr, length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the **NewString()** function which takes **jchar** array and its length. The **NewStringUTF()** function takes UTF-8 encoded C string as input.

See https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html#zz-4.2 for more details.